# FPDF - Fix start position text in cell

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have this part of code to generate PDF (FPDF lib) file with PHP.
He display some text values. I use "Cell" function to put text. But texts start never at the same position : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gof36.png. I think it's due to text length or position of my cell. Could you help me please ? Thanks.

```html
$pdf->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 12 );
$pdf->SetXY( 1, 121 ); $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8); $pdf->Cell( 40, 8, utf8_decode("Type de livraison"), 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->SetXY( 1, 131 ); $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8); $pdf->Cell( 60, 8, utf8_decode("Date et heure livraison souhaitée"), 0, 0, 'C');


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY( 1, 121 ); $pdf->Cell( 88, 8, $lieu_livraison, 0, 0, 'R');
$pdf->SetXY( 1, 131 ); $pdf->Cell( 120, 8, $_POST['date_livraison'] . ' à ' .  $_POST['heure_livraison'], 0, 0, 'R');
```